# Single Slave with Multiple Masters. Does this pattern exist in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, multi-master

Can we have a single mongoDB remotely (online) which can act as a slave to multiple master mongoDBs (which operate offline)?
For example, I have huge number of transactions which I like to perform on my local MongoDBs parallely on multiple systems (offline).
At the end of the day, I want to push minute part of my offline MongoDB records to my single slave MongoDB which is remote and online.
Does this pattern exist?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so Single Slave with Multipe Master Possible. As per **MongoDB BOL** [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/master-slave/) Master-slave replication preceded replica sets and made it possible to have a **large number of non-master** (i.e. `slave`) **nodes**, as well as to restrict replicated operations to only a single database; however, master-slave replication provides less redundancy and does not automate failover.

> **WARNING**
>   Deprecated since version `3.6`: `MongoDB 3.6` deprecates the use of
>   `master-slave replication`.
>
> Master-slave replication has been `deprecated` for components of ***sharded
>   clusters*** `since` **MongoDB 3.2**.

**Replica sets** replace `master-slave replication` for **most** use cases. If possible, use replica sets rather than master-slave replication for all new production deployments. This documentation remains to support legacy deployments and for archival purposes only.

For further your ref [Master Slave Replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/master-slave/)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so. But you can try [mongo-connector](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/tree/master/mongo_connector) to connect to multiple instances and collect and auto populate the data accordingly.